# After every iteration the global list takes new values and doesn't hold the previous one

Tags: c#, list

```
public class trials
{
    public string Tname;
    public List<String> Item=new List<string>();
    public List<String> Duration = new List<string>();
}

List<trials> mtrials = new List<trials>();

List<String> temp_Item = new List<string>();
List<String> temp_Duration = new List<string>();

private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mtrials.Add(new trials { 
              Tname = textBox9.Text, 
              Item = temp_Item,      
              Duration = temp_Duration });
    temp_Duration.Clear();
    temp_Item.Clear();
}
```

The `mtrials`, `temp_Item` and `temp_duration` are global lists. My problem is that after every iteration the `mtrials` value also changes. I don't know why it is happening because once I have given the values to the `mlist`, I am clearing them out so that I can hold new values. The `temp_item` and `temp_duration` are acting as lists for holding lots of data.

Comment: the structure you have is really wierd. Cant you add the Lists into public static class ?

Comment: "*After every iteration*" Where exactly are you iterating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `Clear()` on the list, you're modifying the same reference you just gave to `mtrials`.

```
mtrials.Add(new trials { 
              Tname = textBox9.Text, 
              Item = temp_Item, //<--- This is pointing to the same list    
              Duration = temp_Duration });
temp_Item.Clear();              //<--- As this one. You need to create a new list instead.
```

Replace the clears with:

```
temp_Duration = new List<string>();
temp_Item = new List<string>()
```

Answer (score 1):

`Item = temp_Item; temp_item.Clear ();` You are clearing same list by same reference, so `Item` and `Duration` are always empty. 
You can't skip `temp_item.Clear ();`

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mtrials.Add(new trials { 
              Tname = textBox9.Text, 
              Item = temp_Item,      
              Duration = temp_Duration });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of clearing "temp_Duration" and "temp_Item"
use

string s1 = temp_Duration[temp_Duration.Count - 1];
string s2 = temp_Item[temp_Item.Count - 1];

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnIncarcaLista_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            mtrials.Add(new trials
            {
                Tname = textBox9.Text,
                Item = new List<string>(temp_Item),
                Duration = new List<string>(temp_Duration)
            });
            temp_Duration.Clear();
            temp_Item.Clear();
        }
```

Item = temp_Item creates a reference to temp_Item in the Item field and when you Clear() temp_Item, the Item field is also cleared.
If you create a new list based on temp_Item's information like `Item = new List<string>(temp_Item),` then even if you clear temp_Item, the information will be kept.